# From AWS IoT to DynamoDB using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with AWS IoT. I create a Thing and use MQTT to view the result updated from the Thing Shadow.

$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update

This is the sample result:

```
{"state": {
"desired": null,
"reported": {
  "ext_addr": "0x124b0013a4c55d",
  "last_reported": "22:20:35 2018-10-30",
  "objects": {
    "temperature": {
      "0": {
        "oid": "temperature",
        "sensorValue": 33,
        "units": "Cels",
        "minMeaValue": 33,
        "maxMeaValue": 33
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to store the **"last_reported", "objects"** in separated columns in DynamoDB using Rule to invoke Lambda function. However, I stuck at programming step of the Lambda function.

The table should have items like:

**sensor_id** = ${topic(3)}

**last_reported** = SELECT state.reported.last_reported FROM '$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update'

**data** = SELECT state.reported.objects FROM '$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you *can* use a lambda rule to store IoT data in dynamo, AWS IoT includes a direct-to-dynamo rule, which I think will be much easier for you if you do not have much programming experience:

Create a **DynamoDBv2** action with the following definition:

```
{
    "rule": {
        "ruleDisabled": false, 
        "sql": "SELECT payload.state.reported, topic(3) AS sensor_id FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'", 
        "description": "A test DynamoDBv2 rule", 
        "actions": [{
            "dynamoDBv2": {
                "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws_iot_dynamoDBv2", 
                "putItem": {
                    "tableName": "my_ddb_table"
                }
             }
        }]
    }
}
```

Where:

- `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws_iot_dynamoDBv2` is an IAM role
  that is allowed to put item to your dynamo table
- `my_ddb_table` is
  the name of the table to save the data to

Comment: n.b. if you're looking for a code-free way to store and visualise AWS IoT data, there are products out there. I work for one (https://www.devicepilot.com/) which has a free developer tier.

Comment: thanks for your reply
I tried to create DynamoDBv2 as a rule but I cannot edit hash key and range key as DynamoDBv1
Where can I create a DynamoDBv2 action as you said?

Comment: If you're doing it in the interface, you can see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html that one of the options is "split message into multiple columns (DynamoDBV2)"

Comment: But the option DynamoDBv2 cannot edit the hash key as DynamoDBv1

Comment: The range/hash will be taken from the result of the `SELECT` statement. e.g. if `sensor_id` is your hash key then that'll be set to the result of `topic(3)`. If you tell me your range/hash key names and where they should get their values I'll update the example to be more explicit.

Comment: I can update the data to DynamoDB, but each time it stores new data, it deletes all old data
My rule query statement is:
`SELECT topic(3) AS sensor_id, state.reported.last_reported AS last_reported, state.reported.objects AS data FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update'`